# MySQL stopped working on debian squeez

Tags: mysql, debian

Suddenly and without any reason mysql stopped working.

```
netstat -tap
```

does not list the mysql process. I tried

```
/etc/init.d/mysql restart|start
```

But his produces an error message:

```
/etc/init.d/mysql: error reading input file: Input/output error
```

Any ideas what happend and how do I fix this problem?

Comment: Oh there was a reason, alright. It's now your challenge to figure that out. :)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Oh dear, that sounds like a dead hard drive. I hope you have backups. Try `dmesg` and see if it complains about I/O errors, too.

Comment: you were right, I had to change the hard drive.

Answer (score 1):

try running

```
tail -f /var/log/syslog
```

at the same time when you restart mysql - this should give you some hints.